# ¿Es correcto guardar un objeto en un binario?

Tags: c++

el siguiente código tiene una clase y guarda un objeto en un binario.
Tradicionalmente, se hace un struct que guardará el atributo int en el binario. Pero el código tal como está funciona. Mi pregunta es, puede usarse un código así? Es "legal"? Puede ser peligroso por alguna razón? [Edito: el tamaño del binario resultante es de 4 bytes.]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class A{
    int a;
public: 
    A(int a_):a(a_){}
    ~A(){}

    int Ver(){return a;}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    fstream archivo("dato.dat", ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out | ios::trunc);
    if(!archivo.is_open()){
        cerr << "Error al abrir dato.dat";
    }else{
        A objeto(4);
        archivo.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&objeto),sizeof(objeto));
    }
    archivo.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ¿puede usarse un código así?

Depende.

> Es "legal"?

Depende de lo que entiendas por *legal*. El compilador te dejará hacerlo, pero para ello tendrás que recurrir a conversiones heredadas de C o a `reinterpret_cast`, lo cual ya denota que estás haciendo algo raro.

> Puede ser peligroso por alguna razón?

Por supuesto que sí, sigue leyendo.

En C++ los objetos (ya sean estructuras o clases), son elementos complejos que pueden contener más información de la esperada inicialmente.

El único inconveniente a la hora de guardar la información binaria de un objeto en memoria son los punteros. En C++ es habitual que los objetos almacenen información en la memoria dinámica y, para acceder a dicha información, el objeto hará uso de un puntero. Guardar la información binaria *tal cual* implica que **no se almacenará** la información ubicada en la memoria dinámica, sino que se almacenará el contenido del puntero, es decir, **una dirección de memoria**. Cuando posteriormente se recupere el estado del objeto, casi con toda seguridad la dirección de memoria recuperada será inválida y el programa tendrá dificultades para funcionar con normalidad.

Así, una clase tan habitual en C++ como es la clase `std::string`, así como cualquiera de sus derivadas `QString`, `AnsiString`, ... hacen uso de memoria dinámica. Es fácil ver entonces que a nada que una clase haga uso de cadenas de texto ya tendremos problemas.

Pero es que aunque nuestro objeto no declare punteros ni use clases que tiren de memoria dinámica podemos seguir encontrándonos con problemas... Puede suceder que nuestra clase (o alguna de sus clase base, tenga funciones virtuales). En el momento en el que una clase declara una función como virtual, el compilador creará una tabla de funciones, que no es más que un array de punteros a función. Esta tabla la utilizará el programa para saber a qué función virtual debe llamar en cada momento (la esencia del polimorfismo).

Aunque esta tabla de funciones no está disponible directamente para el programador es fácil demostrar su existencia:

```
#include<iostream>

struct A
{
  virtual ~A() {}
};

struct B
{
  ~B() { }
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << sizeof(A) << ' ' << sizeof(B);
}
```

[En mi caso](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Fu0Ev98ftoPSOPje), el programa devuelve lo siguiente:

```
8 1
```

La clase `A`, al tener funciones virtuales, se ve forzada a usar una tabla de funciones. Dado que el estándar no especifica cómo debe implementarse esta tabla existe la posibilidad de que la misma se encuentre en la memoria dinámica, con lo que volvemos a reproducir el problema de los punteros.

Así pues, para evitar problemas incomprensibles, lo mejor es crear rutinas que *serializen* los diferentes objetos para garantizar que su estado puede ser recuperado posteriormente de forma segura. Es más trabajo pero a cambio consigues una solución robusta y estable.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Entiendo y lo pondré en práctica. Gracias por tu paciencia. Que tengas un excelente año.