# Trabajar con ficheros en C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Tengo el siguiente código, es parte de un programa donde una clase llama a otra desde su interior.

Lo que quería era poder retomar la partida del juego guardando los datos de la clase más interna que es prácticamente la que controla el juego.

El problema es que el código me compila, pero no guarda nada ni carga nada. Revisé los datos de la clase y están como si no hubiera hecho nada.

```
int guardarArchivo() {

    std::ofstream archivo;
    archivo.open("BatallaNaval.dat", 
    std::ios::binary);

    if (archivo.fail()) {
        return 0 ;
    }

    archivo.write((char*)(this),sizeof(this));
    archivo.close();

    setTexto("El archivo se ha guardado");
    escribir2();
    pantalla();

    return 1;
}


int leerArchivo() {
    std::ifstream archivo;
    archivo.open("BatallaNaval.dat", 
    std::ios::binary);

    if (archivo.fail()) {
        return 0;
    }

     archivo.read((char *)(this), 
     sizeof(BatallaNaval));
     archivo.close();

     setTexto("El archivo se ha Cargado");
     escribir2();
     pantalla();
     rest(500);

     return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero que te recomiendo es leerte esta otra [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/226413/463), en la cual explico por qué **no es aconsejable** almacenar la memoria de un objeto directamente.

Lo que tienes que hacer es guardar, manualmente, todos y cada uno de los objetos y variables miembro de `BatallaNaval`:

```
struct BatallaNaval
{
  int filas;
  int columnas;
  std::vector<Barco> barcos;
};

bool guardarArchivo()
{
  archivo << this->filas << this->columnas << this->barcos.size();
  for( Barco const& barco : barcos )
  {
    archivo << barco; // Implementar sobrecarga para `Barco` 
  }
  // ...

  return true; // Es preferible usar bool y true/false a int y 1/0
}

bool leerArchivo()
{
  size_t numBarcos;
  archivo >> this->filas >> this->columnas >> numBarcos;

  for( size_t i=0; i<numBarcos; ++i )
  {
    Barco barco;
    archivo >> barco; // Implementar sobrecarga del operador
    barcos.push_back(std::move(barco));
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta